# cURL- how to submit youtube captcha using cURL

Tags: php, curl, youtube, captcha

i have a php code to get youtube captcha but when i submit captcha Nothing will happen.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.youtube.com/das_captcha?next=/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'session.ck');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 45);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.13 GTB7.1');

$a = curl_exec($ch);
if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r)){
$l = trim($r[1]);

} ?>
```

Can anyone advise me

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The whole point of the captcha is to limit access to humans using web browsers and to block automated tools like the one you appear to be trying to write.

Use [the APIs provided](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) instead.